# Stop Bash Script if Hive Fails

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive

I have a bash script that loops through a folder and processes all *.hql files. Sometimes one of the hive script fails (syntax, resource constraint, etc), instead of the script failing it will continue onto the next .hql file.

Anyway I can stop the bash from processing the remaining? Below is my sample bash:

```
for i in `ls ${layer}/*.hql`; do
      echo "Processing $i ..."
      hive ${hiveconf_all} -hiveconf DATE=${date} -f ${i} &
    if [ $j -le 5 ]; then
       j=$(( j+1 ))
    else
      wait
      j=0
    fi
  done
```

Comment: You mean you want to stop when one of the five concurrent processes fails, right? Since you are intentionally starting more than one at a time. anyway. And I'm not sure you can get the exit status of the processes when done this way. You might need to wait on each one individually to get that I think (or not run them in the background at all).

Comment: Yea good point, would there be a way for me to at least be notified or echo back one that does not get processed? Reason being is sometimes we run 20+ .HQL files and when we run 5 concurrently or more it is sometimes hard to see in the logs if one failed and if we need to re-run it.

Comment: You could use something like `{ hive ... || echo 'SOMETHING EASY TO FIND IN THE LOGS: $?'; } &` and then search for the failure message.

Answer (score 2):

I would check the process completion state of the previous command and invoke the exit command to come out the loop

```
 (( $? == 0 )) && exit 1
```

Introduce the above line after the hive command and should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
set -e
```

to the top of your script

Answer (score 0):

Use this template for running parallel processes and wait for their completion. Add your `date`, `layer`, `hiveconf_all` and other variables:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

#Run parallel processes and write their logs
log_dir=/tmp/my_script_logs
for i in `ls ${layer}/*.hql`; do
      echo "Processing $i ..."
      #Run hive in parallel and redirect to the log file
      hive ${hiveconf_all} -hiveconf DATE=${date} -f ${i} 2>&1 | tee "log_dir/${i}".log &
done

#Now wait for all processes to complete
FAILED=0

for job in `jobs -p`
do
   echo "job=$job"
   wait $job || let "FAILED+=1"
done

if [ "$FAILED" != "0" ]; then
    echo "Execution FAILED!  ($FAILED)"
    #Do something here, log or send message, etc
    exit 1
fi

#All processes are completed successfully!
#Do something here
echo "Done successfully"
```

Then you will be able to inspect each process log individually.