# Hadoop Hive: Generate Table Name and Attribute Name using Bash script

Tags: hadoop, hive

In our environment we do not have access to Hive meta store to directly query.

I have a requirement to generate tablename , columnname pairs for a set of tables dynamically.

I was trying to achieve this by running "describe extended $tablename" to a file for all tables and pick up tablename and column name pairs from the file.

is there any easier way it is done/it can be done other than this way .

The desired output is like

```
table1|col1
table1|col2
table1|col3
table2|col1
table2|col2
table3|col1
```

Answer (score 0):

This script will print columns in desired format for single table. AWK parses strings from describe command, takes only column_name, concatenates with "|" and table_name variable, each string printed with \n as a delimiter between them.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Set table name here
TABLE_NAME=your_schema.your_table

    TABLE_COLUMNS=$(hive -S -e "set hive.cli.print.header=false; describe ${TABLE_NAME};" | awk -v table_name="${TABLE_NAME}" -F " " 'f&&!NF{exit}{f=1}f{printf c table_name "|" toupper($1)}{c="\n"}')
```

You can easily modify it for generating output for all tables using `show tables` command for example.

The easier way is to access metadata database directly.

Comment: Thankyou Leftjoin. Now imagine i have around 20-30 tables as input and if i do not want to login to hive each time , is there an easier way to do it . We do not have access to meta store and i am building a program where we take inputs from users about the tables and i do not want them to wait while hive login happens n number of times

Comment: @NaveenVenugopal You can try to access metastore from Hive using this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48794249/2700344  Unfortunately there is no other easier way.

Comment: @NaveenVenugopal also you can try running shell commands in parallel, just add ampersand at the end, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43825026/2700344